# Curly braces inside JavaScript arguments for functions

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, curly-braces

What do the curly braces surrounding JavaScript arguments for functions do?

```
var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "testing"});
port.postMessage({found: (count != undefined)});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The curly braces denote an object literal. It is a way of sending key/value pairs of data.

So this:

```
var obj = {name: "testing"};
```

Is used like this to access the data.

```
obj.name; // gives you "testing"
```

You can give the object several comma separated key/value pairs, as long as the keys are unique.

```
var obj = {name: "testing",
           another: "some other value",
           "a-key": "needed quotes because of the hyphen"
          };
```

You can also use square brackets to access the properties of the object.

This would be required in the case of the `"a-key"`.

```
obj["a-key"] // gives you "needed quotes because of the hyphen"
```

Using the square brackets, you can access a value using a property name stored in a variable.

```
var some_variable = "name";

obj[ some_variable ] // gives you "testing"
```

Answer (score 213):

A **second possible answer** has arisen since this question was asked. **Javascript ES6** introduced [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
var x = function({ foo }) {
   console.log(foo)
}

var y = {
  bar: "hello",
  foo: "Good bye"
}

x(y)


Result: "Good bye"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. [More here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: This is actually the correct answer, as the question states "for functions".

Answer (score 3):

Curly braces in javascript are used as shorthand to create objects. For example:

```
// Create an object with a key "name" initialized to the value "testing"
var test = { name : "testing" };
alert(test.name); // alerts "testing"
```

Check out Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript Survey](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {title: 'the title'};
```

defines an object literal that has properties on it.  you can  do

```
x.title
```

which will evaluate to 'the title;

this is a common technique for passing configurations to methods, which is what is going on here.