# Javascript - checking for parameters before using them

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I created a popup function and recently changed the format from this:

```
createPopUp('My Popup',600,200);
```

to [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4147003/1358231):

```
createPopUp({ title: 'My Popup', width: 600, height: 200 });
```

I only want to use the values if they exist, so I am currently doing this:

```
function createPopUp(config){

  if (typeof config.title != 'undefined'){
    var theTitle = title;
  } else {
    var theTitle = 'Untitled';
  }

}
```

However this seems very messy so I have been looking for a more efficient way of checking for incoming parameters or setting default values and a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend a default set of properties like this:

```
var defaults = {
    title: 'Untitled',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
}

function createPopUp(config)
{
    var opts = {}

    for (var k in defaults) {
        opts[k] = config[k] || defaults[k];
        // sometimes falsy values should be allowed to override defaults
        // in that case, use this instead:
        // opts[k] = typeof config[k] != 'undefined' ? config[k] : defaults[k]
    }

    // opts contains values from defaults where config doesn't have them
}
```

jQuery has a handy `$.extend()` for this purpose, but you didn't tag your post as such.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I like way you've stored the defaults in one object. I do use jQuery but I like to understand what it's doing first!

Comment: @Jack: Just out of curiousity, but is there any reason why you're using an additional `opts` object? wouldn't `defaults[k] = config[k] || defaults[k];` work just as well? after all, the `defaults` object is constructed each time the function is invoked...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, you're right; for this example I didn't want to "pollute" the contents of `defaults` ... normally I put it outside of the function to be reused, that's why.

Comment: Note that this technique will not work if the caller passes for example `height: 0` or `title: ""`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Well, it will work, but the result might not be what you want it to be :)

Comment: @RaymondChen Yup, but considering that a zero height or empty title are pretty much useless, it would probably not be an issue ;-) but thanks.

Comment: @Jack In this particular example, perhaps, but the next person who copies this answer may have cases where `0`, `""`, or `false` is meaningful. `{ rating: 0, extraPower: false, initialContents: "" }`.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the logical or operator is used for this:

```
var theTitle = config.title || 'Untitled';
```

Basically, the right-hand operand is an expression that will -like all expressions- resolve to a definite value. It's processedd from left to right, so if `config.title` is undefined, the string `'Untitled'` will be the resulting value. 
You can *chain* logical operators if you need to, too:

```
var someVar = obj.val || anotherObject.val || yetAnother.foo || 'bar';
```

Or, if all operands are objects, and you don't know which one exists:

```
var foo = (bar || foobar || {property: 'default: none of the objects exist').property;
```

The object references are grouped together, so JS will first try to resolve the variables (left to right) to an existing value, or, in the end create a new object literal with the desired propert. That reference (the result of the grouped logical-ors) is accessed, and the property `.property` is assigned to foo... I hope this is at least somewhat clear, if not: I'm sorry.

*Caution*
some properties might not be set at the instance level, or might be set, but assigned a falsy value. In that case, the logical OR is not enough, and you'll have to use either a ternary or a regular `if...else`:

```
var foo = (obj.hasOwnProperty('val') ? obj.val : 'default');//<-- uses val property, even if it's undefined, as long as it's set on the instance
//or:
var foo = 'default';
if ('val' in obj)
{//val is set, either on the instance or on its prototype-chain
    foo = obj.val
}
//as ternary:
var foo = ('val' in obj ? obj.val : 'default');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theTitle = 'Untitled';

if('title' in config && config.title != null && config.title.length > 0){
    theTitle = config.title;
}
```

Comment: != null to test if you give it a value or not. It's used to eliminate the case when you might put: config = {title: null, ... }; I forgot to  test if it's empty or no if(config.title.length > 0) ...

Comment: In that case, it's probably better to just write `&& config.title`, to check for truthy values (no emty strings, not null, not undefined, not zero, not false, ...) because if `config.title` is a number, `config.title.length` will throw an error.

Comment: I agree with you. I put this code only for orientation. The above solutions are much better than mine :)